# How to include a credit to be discounted on the total sale value

Tags: paypal

I have a website that allows users to have 'fidelity cards' which at a certain point generate a credit to be used on any sale. Now my problem is that when i connect to PayPal using Express Checkout, i need to submit a list of the products that the user is buying, along with the shipping costs and the total amount of the sale. The total amount of the sale needs to be the same as the sum of the different products multiplied by each of their quantity, otherwise Paypal returns an error. The problem is that i need to deduct the credit that the client is using to the total sale amount, but if the total amount includes the credit already subtracted, then the sum of each indivudual product will result in a different amout from the total sale, which generates an error.
I can include a ficticious product named 'credit', but i'm not sure of two things: can a product have a negative value? Do i have a different form to achieve this?
Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

In reviewing the "Customizing Express Checkout" documents on developer.paypal.com (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/), you may set an item at a negative or positive value, just not 0. When setting the item price, you may provide a negative value to reflect a discount on an order, for example.